# In react js how to send axios GET method request with parameters to Node js and in Node js how to get these parameters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

In react js how to send axios GET method request with parameters to Node js and in Node js how to get these parameters.

I tried below, but not working.

React js sending

(async () => {

```
            const totalDonations = await axios.get(
                                  "http://localhost:3000/api/userdashboard/UserDonorList", {
                                    params: {
                                        assignEvent: props.match.params.event,
                                        userEmail: props.match.params.user
                                    }
                                  }
                                );
            console.log(totalDonations.data)
            setDonationDetailList(list => [...list,...totalDonations])
        })();
```

Node js reading

```
userRouter.get('/api/userdashboard/UserDonorList', userAuth, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    if(!req.user){
    } else {
      const donationInfo = await DonationCreate.find({ userEmail: req.body.userEmail, assignEvent: req.body.assignEvent })
      console.log('donationInfo: ', donationInfo)
      res.status(201).send(donationInfo)
    }
   }
   catch (e) {
    console.log('e: ', e)
    const errors = errorhandle(e)
    res.status(400).send(errors)
   }
});
```

Comment: Probably you need to use POST instead. GET doesn't have params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `req.query` to get access to all the parameter in form of Object in the req object.
Example : `req.query.assignEvent`